# "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process" on gearhost

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Im trying to deploy a net core 2.2 web app on gearhost but im getting an error that says "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."

The app works fine without problems on localhost but everytime i try to publish it to gearhost, i get that error.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\app.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: yes, dont remember exactly how but i think i just killed the cloudsite and made a new one and published again